# Access denied for user 'me'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: mysql, authentication, permissions, linux-mint

I am am trying to learn mysql 101. Doing so, I broke my ability to login as root.

At first I could simply connect to mysql by running

```
sudo mysql
```

In an attempt to alleviate a problem, I thoughtlessly copy and pasted some sql into the mysql prompt.

Specifically...

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

Now when I try to log in using sudo mysql, I get the error...

> Access denied for user 'me'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

What exactly did I do, and how can I rectify it?

EDIT: I tried completely removing mysql with [this article](https://tecadmin.net/remove-mysql-completely-from-linux-system/), and still the same error persists. I have no data I need to preserve, ideally I would just like to nuke mysql and start over.

In fact, I uninstalled mysql, and when I type sudo mysql into the terminal, I get the same error....even with mysql uninstalled??!!!

Comment: do you have username as `me` in mysql?

Comment: try `mysql -u root -ppassword`